# Android Library: Hiding my classes and methods from the user

Tags: android, android-library

I am currently developing an Android library. I don't want to show my inner classes and methods to the user. The solution that I found on the internet is using the `package private` access modifier.

I have implemented some sample classes to test it. Here are the three library classes.

**Class one - LoginLister.java**

```
public interface LoginListener {

   void Login(String username, String password);

}
```

**Class Two - LoginHelper.java**

```
class LoginHelper implements LoginListener{

@Override
public void Login(String username, String password) {
    //The login functionality will implement here. I don't want this code to be visible to the user.
}
```

}

**Class Three - LoginHerperPublic**

```
public class LoginHerperPublic extends LoginHelper {

public LoginHerperPublic(){

}

@Override
public void Login(String username, String password) {
    super.Login(username, password);
}
```

}

The aim of this approach is to show only **LoginHelperPublic** to the user.

After implementing this code, I have created the .aar file and used the .aar file in another sample project.

After adding .aar as a new module, I had able to invoke loginHelperPublic.login() method. From this method, I can able to traverse through all codes of the library.

I went again to the internet for a solution. Found `minifyEnabled true` would solve the issue. Then I build the .aar file by changing the `false` value to `true`.

After making the minifyEnabled true, I can't access any of the class (even LoginHelperPublic) form my sample app.

I hope you understood my requirement. Please give me the right direction.

Comment: With public, private, and protected you should be able to resolve what you want to show (first case) / hide from the developers using your api.

Comment: I can only able to restrict access. using access modifiers. Still they can see the inner methods even it is protected or private.

Comment: minifyEnabled activates Proguard which ofuscastes the output and strips off the code it thinks you don't use. You will need to configur it for it not to remove classes that you need. However this scrambles the apk but won't prevent a developer of using things you have declared public.

Comment: Thanks Juan, I will check it.

Comment: @SunSun you got any solution?

Comment: @LakshyaPunhani: See Juan's comment, it will work.

Comment: Did changing access modifier helped? I also need to do the same and hide my .aar file's code in the main project.